# Facebook API error : Message: (#324) Missing or invalid image file

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am getting an error while uploading an image to Facebook.

Both image and image path are proper but somehow it is not uploaded to Facebook when I am making a `POST` request to `{pageid}/photos` API call.

Here is my code.

```
$photoURL = 'https://www.example.com/images/img.png';
$uploadPhoto = $fb->post('/'.$pageId.'/photos', ['published' => 'false', 'url' => $photoURL]);
```

And it is giving following error.

> Message: (#324) Missing or invalid image file

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe because you're passing `JPG` and facebook accepts only `JPEG`

Comment: I think that's not the case, I checked with png image also & its also not working.

Comment: So I can only say for to check print the `URL` you're sending on `fb->post` and see if is the right one. Also check if all your app configuration is correctly.

Comment: yes, URL is correct & my app is live. are there any specific settings required for app?

Comment: one thing to mention, i have generated token using Graph API explorer using the application i have created & with "publish_pages" permission

Comment: I cannot see what could be the problem...if you're the owner of the page, `publish_pages` shouldn't be a problem. There's others configuration like the server thats allowed do make request...you could check this also!

Comment: I uploaded the same image on other server & it worked. so is it something related to server settings?

Comment: its possible that your server is not accepting facebook request, so, the image is invalid to the facebook api...

Comment: it look like facebook upgrade its version from time to time and if not followed with it it gives api error

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to post from your localhost or virtualhost then error occurs because **facebook can not find the url** that you are providing.

**Try this way:**
search image from internet and pass its address to facebook SDK. I will post successfullty.

I was trying to send image from my virtualhost http:app.local.com/image-address and it gave same error. Then I picked an image form internet and passed then it was posted successfully.

Hope it solves your issue

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the SSl certificate.  It was on the server and valid over https, however I had an incorrect intermediate certificate on there.  I saw the error when I checked the domain

https://cryptoreport.geotrust.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp

Thanks

Grant